# Cannot read property 'enableMenuWithBackViews' in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

When i click on a link on my app that navigate to another page, this error appears on console, everything is running normal, and the app don't crash, but is annoying, and i don't know what is causing it. Its some bug?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are trying to call this method `enableMenuWithBackViews`...please take a look at your code!

Comment: but i  find but can't meet **enableMenuWithBackViews**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I used class "menu_toggle". When I changed it, bug was fixed

Answer (score -1):

I commented this out in ionic.bundle.js to "fix" it:
Starting with line no. 56917

For more info go for this link. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-read-property-enablemenuwithbackviews-of-undefined/18201

```
    if (viewData.enableBack) {
    var sideMenuCtrl = $element.inheritedData('$ionSideMenusController');
    if (!sideMenuCtrl.enableMenuWithBackViews()) {
        $element.addClass('hide');
    }
} else {
    $element.removeClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix anything. The problem is within the code, not Ionic itself.

Answer (score -1):

That means that there is something wrong on your template xml code, near to the `<ion-nav-buttons>` element. I had the same problem before. That's *not* an Ionic bug.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is within the code, not Ionic itself. For your answer:
In ion-nav-buttons element, just remove menu-toggle attribute, example: menu-toggle="right" or menu-toggle="left"